# using a private variable for the lock of synchronized block

Tags: variables, locking, block, private, synchronized

hi there i am working on threads and implement some simple examples with them. In addition, i know how to lock and use a synchronized statement but i saw an example like this;

```
private List<Foo> myList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
private Map<String,Bar) myMap = new HashMap<String,Bar>();

public void put( String s, Bar b ) {
  synchronized( myMap ) {
    myMap.put( s,b );
    // then some thing that may take a while like a database access or RPC or notifying listeners
  }
}
```

so how and why can be a variable used as a lock of a synchronized block_?. i always using "this" word for accessing to the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, each object instance has a lock associated with it. 
You need a object's reference in order to do a synchronized block statement.
It's not necessary to use the same object for a synchronized block. You would be perfectly fine with this:

```
private Map<String,Bar) myMap = new HashMap<String,Bar>();
private Object lockObj = new Object();

public void put( String s, Bar b ) {
  synchronized( lockObj ) {
    myMap.put( s,b );
    // then some thing that may take a while like a database access or RPC or notifying listeners
  }
}
```

But the trick now, is to make sure you use the same object whenever you access myMap object. 
So it's a good practice to use the same object that you operation on, to act as a lock..
This is used when you want to do a small synchronized block and don't bother creating a new object for it.. this will work fine for that.
I hope that helped you understand java's synchronization approach.

Regards,
Tiberiu

Comment: well mate this is the most clear and understandable info for me :). thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can use any reference type that does not have a weak identity to lock a block of code. It is a general practice to use the `this` pointer. But whether you should use a member variable depends on the behavior of your class.

For instance if you have four methods out of which two use `var1` and the other two use `var2`. Now if you want to synchronize these methods only based on these variables then you could choose to use the variables to lock instead of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

this is a pointer to the current object, but myMap is also an object, an instance of the class HashMap which implements the Serializable interface